# Как добавить вторую базу данных в sqlDelight?

Tags: android, kotlin

Я хочу добавить вторую базу данных в проект, но получаю ошибку на строчке где начинается `android { ... }` в build.gradle:

`No signature of method: build_6btqp7jxipjfe95thsknjaq5k.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_6btqp7jxipjfe95thsknjaq5k$_run_closure1) values: [build_6btqp7jxipjfe95thsknjaq5k$_run_closure1@1b25aa84]`

Пробовал вот так:

структура проекта:

```
main
 groupEntity
  com
   example
    kaiapp
     groupEntity.sq
 loginEntity
  com
   example
    kaiapp
     loginEntity.sq
```

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'
    sqldelight{
        GroupDatabase{
            packageName = "com.example.kaiapp"
            sourceFolders = listOf("groupEntity")
        }

        LoginDatabase{
            packageName = "com.example.kaiapp"
            sourceFolders = listOf("loginEntity")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может как-то так надо делать? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601394/5479247

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja пробовал создавать директории типа main/groupEntity/com/example/kaiapp/groupEntity.sq, такая же ошибка